# How to hide routes in vue router based in condition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I want to hide a route based on a condition that return true or false.
I have a list of routes, for example:
- Products
- Clients

When a user logins and no have the action for editing products, then, the new list would be only:
-Clients.

I hide another routes based on the name: `v-for="item in routes" v-if="item.name != 'Login"`.

For hidding buttons, i use this:

```
AccionRegistrarProducto(){
        var userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));
        var acciones = userData.infoUser.Acciones;
        if(acciones.some(a => a.Accion === 'Agregar Productos')){
            this.accionRegistrarProducto = true;
        }
        else{
            this.accionRegistrarProducto = false;
        }
    },
```

And i want to replicate this for routes list.

Comment: Can we see how you define your routes?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable routes based on some condition you can use navigation guards in your router.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => { // this executes before entering as the name suggests.
        // you can also have this function inside a component
        // ...
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

With your code example it would look like this

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo', //the path you are trying to disable
      component: Foo, //the component
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        var userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));
        var acciones = userData.infoUser.Acciones;
        if(acciones.some(a => a.Accion === 'Agregar Productos')){
            next() // changes route
        }
        else{
            next(false) // doesn't allow changing route, you can also do redirects here etc.
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

More here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: I would like to know how to _hide_ (visibly) the route in the menu.